# jQuery.grep and more than 1 condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var matches = $.grep($.trolley, function(element){ 
    if ((element.id == grocery.id) && (element.dimensions == grocery.dimensions)) {
        console.log('t'); 
    } else { 
        console.log('f'); 
    } 
});
```

So I have say 3 items. `id 1 dimensions 4, id 2 dimensions 8, id 2 dimensions 8`

I want to find the item that isn't in the array, but as soon as it matches an item in the array that already has that `id`, it returns a match... Even though the `dimensions` differ :(

http://jsfiddle.net/justrealmilk/6SSKj/

Comment: It shouldn't. How are you testing this code? Can you provide a self-contained example?

Comment: The behavior you describe would happen if you used `||` instead of `&&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter function needs to return `true` or `false` depending on whether the test succeeds (actually, only the `true` case is required, but doing both is cleaner, IMHO):

```
var matches = $.grep($.trolley, function(element){ 
    if ((element.id == grocery.id) && (element.dimensions == grocery.dimensions)) {
        console.log('t'); 
        return true;
    } else { 
        console.log('f');
        return false;
    } 
});
```

Since you weren't returning anything, it implicitly returns `undefined`, which should have been resulting in an empty `matches`. I'm not sure why you were getting anything, let alone just the first matching `id`.

Comment: It is writing 't' to console even when false, still :(

Comment: Try doing `console.log('t', element, grocery);`, maybe these things don't contain what you think they contain.

Comment: Don't see where this is on that site. Can you make a SSCE in a fiddle?

Comment: Here's the problem: Every time you do `grocery = $(this).data('post')` it's returning the same object, not a new copy. That object, not a copy, was also pushed onto `$.trolley`. So when you do `grocery.dimensions = $('select').find(":selected").text();` you're modifying the object that's in `$.trolley`. So the dimensions match because they're the same object.

Comment: I'm very confused. I thought I was grabbing the data from the button, adjusting value of that new object based on a string from the page, and then comparing it with $.trolley

Comment: jQuery is pulling a trick on you. It emulates its original definition of `.data()` as associating real objects with DOM elements. So it only creates a new object from the `data-post` attribute the first time, then it reuses that object from then on. Use `$.parseJSON($(this).attr('data-post'))` to get a new object each time.

Comment: I've tried and tried to make this work beyond the example but it keeps returning null, possibly because it's an object, not a string? I don't know how to write what I've written any other way unfortunately... After reading some API docs, I gave .removeData() a go but it blew up in my face also. Is there any other way to resolve the internal cache issue?

Comment: Didn't my `$.parseJSON` suggestion work? Or see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object for a way to clone an object in jQuery.

Comment: I meant I tried and tried with your suggestion... I don't understand why I'd want to clone an object

Comment: The reason to clone the object is so that the object you push on `$.trolley` is not the same object that you pull out of `$(this).data('post')`, so modifying the latter doesn't also modify the former. See http://jsfiddle.net/6SSKj/2/